# displaying time in unix?

Tags: unix, time

Is there a way to display a timestamp before every command line in UNIX or Mac OS X?

This is what shows up:

```
[projects]$ make
```

This is roughly what I want:

```
(1/13/2012 12:46.34) [projects]$ make
```

EDIT:
This is what I get from 'echo $PS1':

```
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

I want this same functionality but with a timestamp.  I am not too familiar with the PS1 variable and its syntax but when I try and put in what echo spits out + a date, it messes all up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your shell.  If you are using bash:

```
export PS1='\D{%D %H:%M.%S} [\W]\$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date` command.

> date - print or set the system date and time

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_date.htm

Comment: ..and add this "date" program output into shell $PS1 variable.
:)

Answer (score 1):

Set your PS1 variable with `date` command.

```
export PS1=$(date):$PWD $
```

PS1 is usually set in your `.basrc` file or `.profile` which you can find in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can type

```
PS1="($(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) [\W]\$ "
```

then press enter. If you like how it looks, put that line at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.